# Adicionar atributo CLASS em Option de select widget django

Tags: python, django

Estou usando um `widget=forms.Select()` em um `forms.Form` do Django, porém, ao tenta adicionar um atributo CLASS em Options, que faz parte de Select, não consigo, somente no próprio Select, andei procurando e só encontrei opções de Override do código Django, acredito que tenha algo mais simples no Django, uma opção que me passou despercebido...

Comment: Você poderia explicar o motivo de querer colocar `class` nos `<option>`?

Comment: Quero fazer uma solução usando o JQuery, preciso capturar um valor na CLASS.

Comment: Você está equivocado. Se você quer manipular um option através de Jquery, você pode selecionar a opção buscando por seu `value` e não por sua class.